# Selenium Grid 4 on different public IP machines

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am using Selenium Grid 4 (4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210402) and trying to build the hub and the node at different machines. I want the hub at a GCP VM instance and the node at an Azure WIndows virtual machine with a desktop.

I had the hub working with

```
$ docker run -d -p 4442-4444:4442-4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210402
```

and the node working with

```
$ docker run -d -p 5555:5555 
    -e SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=<public-ip-from-GCP-VM> \
    -e SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442 \
    -e SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443 \
    -e SE_NODE_HOST=<public-ip-from-Azure-VM> \
    -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm \
    selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210402
```

Both work stations can ping each other, but the hub doesn’t seem to notice the node. Am I missing something?